# Is it possible to armature a multiple objects?

Tags: armature

I have a model with weapon and shield separated in objects, but im having a difficulty because i have to merge those objects before adding armature and weights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Each object can be parented and weighted to the one armature in the same way you would a single model.

Comment: Do i have to manually add weight if i did connect armature to my mesh?

Comment: You can use automatic weights. Just parent each mesh one by one. you may not get good automatic results for the weapon or shield though

Comment: one last question, How to set parent lol >,< sorry im so noob

Comment: Select the mesh and hold down shift to select the armature as well then press ctrl-p